# How to use mage.exe to resign manifests for VSTO?

Tags: c#, clickonce, mage

We have an Excel plugin as part of our Visual Studio solution. The plugin is built once and then deployed out to different environments (dev, uat, prod) as part of our CI/CD process.

During the deploys we apply an app config transform to update the Excel plugin config with the correct environmental config.

As such, the manifest and VSTO needs resigning. I've been through a number of SO posts ([Use mage.exe to create a ClickOnce deployment manifest for *.deploy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777441/use-mage-exe-to-create-a-clickonce-deployment-manifest-for-deploy-files), [Resign manifest of click-once application change from 4.0 to 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858584/resign-manifest-of-click-once-application-change-from-4-0-to-4-5), [Resign Clickonce manifest using mage.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004056/resign-clickonce-manifest-using-mage-exe) etc.) and MSDN posts and cannot work out the correct way to call `mage.exe` for this to work.

I've tried `mage.exe -update ...`, `mage.exe -sign ...` and a couple of other combinations that all result in broker or invalid manifests when I try to launch the VSTO e.g.

```
C:\Tools\mage.exe -update "$CodeBasePath\MyCompany.vsto" -certFile "$CertFile" -password "$CertPassword" -appManifest "$AppManifestPath"
```

Does anything know the correct order of signing and flags to use with `mage.exe` when re-signing a VSTO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

before updating the VSTO file you need to first update the application manifest.

mage -update yourFile.dll.manifest -CertFile certificate.pfx -Password password

Then you need to update the VSTO with the application manifest you already updated.

mage -update yourFile.vsto -appmanifest yourFile.dll.manifest -CertFile certificate.pfx -Password password

Answer (score 0):

just additional info to the above correct answer is, incase using Certificate Store or USB Token, then you need to provide -CertHash "certificate thumbprint" instead of -CertFile "certificate file path"

mage -update yourFile.dll.manifest -CertHash "cert-thumb-print"